# Display parsed XML in data frame

Tags: xml, r, xpath, xml-parsing, dataframe

I am trying to parse XML in R using the XML package by Duncan Temple Lang. The aim of the function is to parse any XML data given to it and produce output in a data.frame as shown in the desired output below. The getValues function is meant to produce list of attribute names and its associated values which then get passed into a data frame when called. But it doesn't work that way as not all attribute names and values appear in the data frame. Please see below for sample XML and the output I am currently getting.

```
library(XML)

getValues <- function(x) {
    aList <- list()

    #attributes
    if(!is.null(xmlAttrs(x))) {
        num.attributes = xmlSize(xmlAttrs(x))
        for (i in seq_len(num.attributes)) {      
            attributeName <- names(xmlAttrs(x)[i])
            attributeValue <- xmlAttrs(x)[[i]]         
            aList <- append(aList, c(Name = attributeName, Text = attributeValue))
        }
    }
    return(aList)
}

retrieveStructureInfo <- function(node) {  
    if (is.null(node)) {
        return()
    }

    nkids <- xmlSize(node)

    bypass <- function(n = nkids) {
        if(nkids == 0) {
           xpathApply(xmlParent(node), path = xpath, fun = getValues)
        } else {
           return(nkids)
        }
    }

    #children is the no. of nodes within a node
    for (i in 1 : children) {
      #recursive function call
      retrieveStructureInfo(node[[i]]) 
    }
}

#parse xml document
#xmlfile is the file path
doc <- xmlParse(xmlfile)
r <- xmlRoot(doc)
data <- data.frame(node = NA, value = NA)
retrieveStructureInfo(r)
data
```

Sample XML:

```
<CATALOG>
   <PLANT>
      <COMMON Source="a" Available="false">Bloodroot</COMMON>
      <LOCATION></LOCATION>
      <PARENT />
   </PLANT>
   <PLANT>
      <COMMON Source="b" Available="true">Columbine</COMMON>
      <LOCATION>Africa</LOCATION>
      <PARENT />
   </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

Output:

```
                  node       value
                source           a
                source           b
```

Desired Output:

```
                  node       value
                source           a
             available       false
                source           b
             available        true
```

Comment: Yes but that time I wasn't able to add rows to the data.frame correctly. Now I'm facing issue when parsing a large XML file.

Comment: @RichardScriven I seen your post but it was deleted few days ago. I have resolved the issues that I had and now have come upon this new error. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer this yesterday and point out that everything in your desired output is already in the xmlToList output.  You could probably even parse the path column below to get parent, type and other columns.

```
x <- xmlParse( your sample XML with <root> tags added) 
y <- xmlToList(x)
z <- unlist(y)
data.frame(path=names(z), value=z)
                                   path     value
1             CATALOG.PLANT.COMMON.text Bloodroot
2    CATALOG.PLANT.COMMON..attrs.Source         a
3 CATALOG.PLANT.COMMON..attrs.Available     false
4             CATALOG.PLANT.COMMON.text Columbine
5    CATALOG.PLANT.COMMON..attrs.Source         b
6 CATALOG.PLANT.COMMON..attrs.Available      true
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. Do you think you can help me look into the issue I am currently having. I have updated my post.